# mysql query to insert photo details in database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to build a query to insert photo details in database tables. Here's my tables structure:

```
photos(photo_id, photo_title, caption, ....)
tags(tag_id, tag_name)
tag_asc(tag_id, photo_id)
```

A photo has title, caption, and tags array. I want to:

1. Insert photo_title and caption in photos table.
2. Insert each of tag from tags array in tags table.
3. Insert tag_id and photo_id in tag_asc table (to link tags with photos).

I have come up with following three queries to do above task.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (photo_title, caption) 
             VALUES ($title, $caption)");
$photo_id = mysql_insert_id();  //get photo_id

foreach ($tags as $tag){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) 
               VALUES ($tag)");

  $tag_id = mysql_insert_id(); //get tag_id 

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO tag_asc (tag_id, photo_id) 
               VALUES ($tag_id, $photo_id)");                 
}
```

### My question

If the above approach is good, or if there is more efficient way to do same thing?

Comment: You could do this entire operation within a stored procedure, which would save on the transfer over the wire because you'd use a single query to the database.  Supporting the tag insertion would require some work to support multiple tags though - there's a risk of having more data than the data type would support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what you're doing looks fine. The main problem I see is the potential for duplicate tags.

It would be better to check if a tag exists and fetch the existing tag's ID if it does, rather than creating a new tag each time. This would prevent duplicate tag names from being inserted into the `tags` table. If you know each tag is unique, this could speed things up later — for example, you could search photos by their tag IDs rather than having to do some messy `JOIN` stuff.

- Give `tags.tag_name` a unique index if it doesn't have one already.
- Use the following function to fetch a tag ID. If the tag already exists, the existing row ID will be returned. If not, a new row will be created and its ID will be returned.

-

```
function select_or_create_tag($tag_name) {
    $tag_name = addslashes($tag_name);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag_name='$tag_name'");

    if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
        return mysql_result($result, 0, 0);

    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES ('$tag_name')");
    return mysql_insert_id($insert);
}
```

Example usage, based on your code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (photo_title, caption) 
             VALUES ($title, $caption)");
$photo_id = mysql_insert_id();

foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_id = select_or_create_tag($tag);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tag_asc (tag_id, photo_id) 
           VALUES ($tag_id, $photo_id)");
}
```

---

Also:

- Make sure you have non-unique indices set up on `tag_asc.tag_id` and `tag_asc.photo_id` for faster querying.
- As [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies) mentioned, it might be worth converting this code to a stored SQL procedure. That would get rid of a lot of the overhead involved with making all these SQL queries individually.

Comment: Thanks for such a helpful answer. About unique index to tags_name, did you mean I should make `tag_name` a UNIQUE KEY ?

Comment: No problem! A unique key and unique index are the same. If the table's already created you can add one using [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html). If not, add a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint to your [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) statement.